# Calculate A(N) / B(N) with C(N) digits

Tags: code-golf, sequence, division

Consider three number sequences, \$A\$, \$B\$ and \$C\$:

- \$A\$: A sequence based on recurrence relations, \$f(n) = f(n-1)+f(n-2)\$, starting with \$f(1) = 3, f(2) = 4\$. So, the sequence begins like this: \$3, 4, 7, 11, 18, 29, 47, 76, ...\$
- \$B\$: The [composite numbers](https://oeis.org/A002808), that is all integers that aren't primes (or 1): \$4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16, ...\$
- \$C\$: The digits of \$\pi\$: \$3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, ...\$

Given a positive integer \$N < 50\$, either as function argument or STDIN, return the decimal value of the fraction \$\frac{A(N)}{B(N)}\$ with \$C(N)\$ digits after the decimal point. Normal rules for rounding applies (round up if the \$N+1\$'th digit is 5 or higher). If the Nth digit of \$\pi\$ is zero, an integer should be printed. [scientific notation / Standard form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) is accepted for numbers higher than 1000.

This is code golf, so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Some examples:

```
N = 1: 0.750
N = 2: 0.7
N = 3: 0.8750
N = 4: 1.2
N = 6: 2.416666667
N = 10: 11.056
N = 20: 764.8750
```

Of course, standard code golf rules applies.

The function must terminate in less than two minutes on any modern laptop.

Comment: When you say `C(n)` digits, do we have to include trailing 0's?

Comment: To which input does the time limit apply?

Comment: @Dennis, do you mean to which `N`? If so, up to N = 49. Or something else?

Comment: JavaScript has a limited floating point accuracy of 16. Past that you'll start getting inaccurate results. Is this okay?

Comment: @vihan My solution (unpublished ATM) stores the first 49 digits of pi in a string. And you don't need any more than 9 digits of accuracy in the result, if you're worried about that.

Comment: @vihan, I think ETHproductions answered it well. You only need to output 9 digits after the decimal points. Those 9 should be exact. There are algorithms for calculating only the N'th digit of pi (I'll admit: I don't know how big accuracy you need to calculate the 49th). You can also follow ETHprocuctions tips.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Pyth, <s>60</s> <s>57</s> 58 bytes

```
.[K`.Rchu,eGsGQjT7e.ftPZQ)Je/u+/*GHhyHy^TQr^T3ZZT\0+xK\.hJ
```

[Test harness](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.%5BK%60.Rchu%2CeGsGQjT7e.ftPZQ%29Je%2Fu%2B%2F%2aGHhyHy%5ETQr%5ET3ZZT%5C0%2BxK%5C.hJ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A6%0A10%0A20%0A33%0A49&debug=0)

It's pretty straightforward - calculate pi, the fibonacci series and the composites, round to C(n) digits, pad to C(n) digits plus the location of the decimal point digits, done.

A(n): `hu,eGsGQjT7`

B(n): `e.ftPZQ)`

C(n): `e/u+/*GHhyHy^TQr99ZZT`

60 -> 57: Cleaned up the n = 1 special case in the pi calculation.

57 -> 58: Wasn't using high enough precsion for pi for the entire input range - increased 99 iterations to 1000 iterations.

**Note on rounding:** This uses Python's "nearest even" rounding system, rather than the OP specified "towards infinity" system. However, the difference only matters if the digits immediately following the rounding point are `5000...`, e.g. 1.25 rounded to 1 digit. I checked the input range, and this never happens, so the correct result is alway returned.

Answer (score 2):

## PowerShell, <strike>420 Bytes (ayyyyyyyy)</strike> 378 Bytes

```
param($n);[int[]]$p="03141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375"-Split'';$a=@(0,3,4);for($i=3;$i-lt50;$i++){$a+=$a[$i-1]+$a[$i-2]};$c=[char[]]"00001010111010111010111011111010111110111010111011111011111010111110111";$b=@(0);for($i=4;$i-le70;$i++){if($c[$i]-eq'1'){$b+=$i}};[double]$r=$a[$n]/$b[$n];$q=$p[$n+1];$s="";(0..($q-1))|%{$s+="0"};([math]::Round($r,$q,[MidpointRounding]::AwayFromZero)).ToString("0.$s")
```

<sub>Thanks to [isaacg](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/56013/42963) for saving 41 bytes, for calculating how the question does rounding. Means I didn't have to include the horrendous `[MidpointRounding]::AwayFromZero` and didn't need to explicitly cast as a `[double]`.</sub>

This one was great fun!

#### Expanded:

```
# Take input N
param($n)

# First digits of pi, stored as integer array
[int[]]$p="03141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375"-Split''

# Fibonacci sequence A(N)
$a=@(0,3,4)
for($i=3;$i-lt50;$i++){
  $a+=$a[$i-1]+$a[$i-2]
}

# Zero-indexed bitmask for if the n-th integer is composite (1) or not (0)
$c=[char[]]"00001010111010111010111011111010111110111010111011111011111010111110111"

# Populate B(N) as an array using the $c mask
$b=@(0)
for($i=4;$i-le70;$i++){
  if($c[$i]-eq'1'){
    $b+=$i
  }
}

# Calculation Time!
$r=(a($n))/$b[$n]

# A small golf, as $p[$n+1] gets used a couple times
$q=$p[$n+1]

# Need to generate a string of zeroes for padding
$s=""
(0..($q-1))|%{$s+="0"}

# Round the number, then send it to a string so we get the necessary number of zeroes
([math]::Round($r,$q)).ToString("0.$s")
```

Recursion in PowerShell is ... slow, shall we say, so we have to build `A(N)` the other direction and store it into an array, then index it.

---

#### OLD

Also, holy cow, did the output requirements kill this. PowerShell defaults to rounding-to-nearest a/k/a banker's rounding, which necessitates utilizing the extraordinarily verbose `[MidpointRounding]::AwayFromZero` to switch [rounding styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx#Midpoint). On top of that, we then needing to pad trailing zeroes, if any. Those two requirements combined to turn the last couple of lines from **20 Bytes** `[math]::Round($r,$q)` to **102 Bytes** (from the `$s=""` to `+$s)`) ... wow.

Comment: Great description/commenting! 32 chars for `[MidpointRounding]::AwayFromZero` alone is almost too good/bad to be true... =)

Comment: See my note on rounding in my answer. PowerShell default rounding should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (ES6), 302 bytes

One word: Unfinished.

```
x=>{a=[0,3,4],b=[0],c='03141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375';for(i=1;i<x;a[i+2]=a[i]+a[++i]);for(i=1,p=[];++i<70;v=p.every(x=>i%x),(v?p:b).push(i));r=''+Math.round(a[x]/b[x]*(l=Math.pow(10,c[x])))/l;if(x==33)return r;r.indexOf`.`<0&&(r+='.');while(!r[r.indexOf`.`+ +c[x]])r+='0';return r}
```

The first 49 digits of pi are stored in a string, and the other two sequences are auto-generated. This has been golfed about halfway; I'm (almost) sure I could squeeze another 50 bytes out of it.

Works for all the test cases, and should work for the rest. Crashes on anything more than 49 or less than 0 (it should never encounter these situations anyway). I especially like its result for 0:

```
NaN.
```

Comment: Why is this unfinished?

Comment: @BetaDecay I meant I haven't finished golfing it yet. I will as soon as I have the time.

Answer (score 1):

## Octave, <del>276</del> 236 Bytes

First of all I thought it would be cool to make use of some unlimited accuracy in these mathematical tools (and to refresh some knowledge about it) so I started writing some algorithms and then ended finally found out that the `pi` value is not so accurate that I will have to use the array again. So again, no great success:

```
function c(A)p="3141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375";f=ones (1,50);f(1)=3;f(2)=4;for i=3:53f(i)=f(i-1)+f(i-2);end
i=0;x=1;while i<A
x++;for j=2:x/2
if mod(x,j)==0 i++;break;end end end
printf(["%." p(A) "f\n"],f(A)/x);end
```

Still quite readable, isn't it?

### Usage

copy-paste function into octave, call function `c` with argument of required value:

```
>>> c(1)
0.750
>>> c(49)
407880480.04348
```

Optimizations:

- Substitute `endif`, `endfor` and similar with `end` which works the same way
- decreasing variable `i` by one save one byte
- remove `num2str(str2num(p(A)))` nonsense :)

Comment: I like that you posted a Octave solution (I'm a MATLAB guy myself!). Note that this code is Octave only, not MATLAB. MATLAB uses `end`, not `endif`, so many bytes saved. If you also happen to have the symbolic toolbox for MATLAB, you can use [`vpa`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html) to get enough decimal points for pi: `vpa(sym(pi),49)`. I don't have it at this laptop, so I'm not sure if the `sym` is necessary there, but should save quite some bytes anyways =) And readable is not necessarily a good thing in code golf =)

Comment: x++ is also not a MATLAB command. I didn't know there were such large differences between the two... IMO, it shouldn't be. I think all code written in Octave should be portable to MATLAB (but not necessarily the other way around as MATLAB has more options).

Comment: Approved your edit. I don't have matlab around here so I was unable to test it. I was searching for solution to get more pi decimals in octave, but nothing was shorter than just array, unfortunately. But ommiting `while` from `endwhile` and similar works fine, so I'm updating the answer with few less characters :)