# Composite Number Sequences

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence, number-theory, primes

<sub>Inspired by [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/56006/calculate-an-bn-with-cn-digits) question</sub>

Given a positive integer \$n\$, your code must output the first \$n\$ composite numbers.

**Input / Output**

You may write a program or a function. Input is through STDIN or function argument and output is to STDOUT, or function return value.

Output can be a List, Array, or String.

**Examples**

```
 0 -> 
 1 -> 4
 2 -> 4, 6
 3 -> 4, 6, 8
13 -> 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21, 22
```

---

### Rules

- As always [standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are disallowed.
- Built-ins that generate prime or composite numbers are not allowed.
- Built-ins relating to prime or composite numbers are not allowed.

Comment: Of course, it's on OEIS: [A002808](https://oeis.org/A002808)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Pyth - 10 bytes

A valid answer. Uses [Wilson's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem).

```
.f%h.!tZZQ
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.f%25h.%21tZZQ&input=13&debug=0).

### Old answer

### Pyth - 6 chars

Uses builtin for *prime factorization*, not prime checking.

```
.ftPZQ
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.ftPZQ&input=13&debug=0).

```
.f  Q         First n that passes filter of lambda Z, uses input for how many
 t            Tail. This makes all that have len-one prime factorization become empty list, and thus falsey.
  P           Prime factorization - primes have a len-one factorization.
   Z          Lambda var
```

Comment: Hm, should of thought about that :/

Comment: The rules have changed and thus this answer is no longer valid.

Comment: @orlp updated answer.

Comment: @Maltysen Isn't this 10 bytes?

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos :/ I apparently can't read the length counter. Fixing.

Answer (score 8):

## Pyth, 11 bytes

```
<S{*M^tSQ2Q
```

Generates overly large list of products of all combinations of [2, n] and truncates.

Comment: It does not work if the input is `1` or `2`.

Answer (score 7):

## TeX, 382 bytes

Because you can.

```tex
\newcount\a\newcount\b\newcount\c\newcount\n\newcount\p\newcount\q\let\v\advance\let\e\else\let\z\ifnum
\def\d#1:#2:#3:{\z#1>#2\v#1 by-#2\d#1:#2:#3:\e\z#1=#2#3=1\e#3=0\fi\fi}
\def\i#1:#2:#3:{#3=0\z#1>#2\a=#1\d\a:#2:\c:
\z\c=0\b=#2\v\b by 1\i#1:\the\b:#3:\e#1\par\fi\e#3=1\fi}
\def\l#1:#2:#3:#4:{\i\the#1:2:#4:
\z#4=0\v#2 by 1\fi\z#2<#3\v#1 by 1\l#1:#2:#3:#4:\fi}
\l\p:\n:10:\q:\end
```

The number in the last line is the number of composite numbers you want to have.

This is a simple divisor tester. `\d` checks if `#2` divides `#1`. `\i` calls  `\d` for all possible dividers (i.e. < `#1`). `\l` lists the first `#2` numbers for which `\i` returns 0.

Ungolfed (well, half-golfed) version:

```tex
\newcount\a
\newcount\b
\newcount\c
\newcount\n
\newcount\p
\newcount\q

\def\div#1:#2:#3:{%
  \ifnum#1>#2 %
    \advance#1 by-#2 %
    \div#1:#2:#3:%
  \else%
    \ifnum#1=#2 %
      #3=1%
    \else%
      #3=0%
    \fi%
  \fi%
}

\long\def\isprime#1:#2:#3:{%
  #3=0%
  \ifnum#1>#2 %
    \a=#1 %
    \div\a:#2:\c: %
    \ifnum\c=0 %
      \b=#2 %
      \advance\b by 1 %
      \isprime#1:\the\b:#3:%
    \else
      #1\par%
    \fi%
  \else%
    #3=1%
  \fi%
}

\def\listprimes#1:#2:#3:#4:{%
  \isprime\the#1:2:#4: %
  \ifnum#4=0 %
    \advance#2 by 1 %
  \fi
  \ifnum#2<#3 %
    \advance#1 by 1 %
    \listprimes#1:#2:#3:#4: %
  \fi
}

\listprimes\p:\n:11:\q:

\end
```

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf! Great first answer in a language nobody thought would be suitable for the challenge. Although it is pretty long, it is unique and neat answering in TeX and we certainly appreciate such answers.

Comment: @TanMath thanks for the warm welcome, I realize this is too long to compete, but it was fun :)

Answer (score 6):

### Python, 57

```python
lambda n:sorted({(k/n+2)*(k%n+2)for k in range(n*n)})[:n]
```

Less golfed:

```python
def f(n):
 R=range(n)
 return sorted({(a+2)*(b+2)for a in R for b in R})[:n]
```

The idea is to generate the set of composite numbers by multiplying all pairs of natural numbers except 0 and 1. Then, sort this set, and take the first `n` elements. It suffices to take the Cartesian product of the set `{2, 3, ..., n+2}` with itself, which we can get by shifting `range(n)` up by 2.

To golf this, we do a classic golfing trick of storing two values `(a,b)` in `range(n)` as a single value `k` in `range(n*n)`, and extract them as `a=k/n, b=k%n`.

Answer (score 4):

## Java 8, <s>98</s> 97 bytes

```
i->{int a[]=new int[i],c=3,k=0,d;for(;k<i;c++)for(d=c;d-->2;)if(c%d<1){a[k++]=c;break;}return a;}
```

Expanded, with boilerplate:

```
public class C {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Function<Integer, int[]> f = i -> {
            int a[] = new int[i], c = 3;
            for (int k = 0; k < i; c++) {
                for (int d = c; d --> 2;) {
                    if (c % d < 1) {
                        a[k++] = c;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return a;
        };
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(f.apply(5)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

## R, 53 bytes

```
n=scan();t=1:(n*n+3);t[factorial(t-1)%%t!=(t-1)][1:n]
```

**How it works**

This is also based on [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem) and all it does is to run over a range of `1:n*n` and extract the composite numbers according to the above mentioned theorem. I've added `+3` because `n*n` isn't big enough range for `n < 3` integers

---

The only problem with this solution is that (sadly) R loses precision for a big enough factorial, thus, this won't work properly for `n > 19`

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, <s>20</s> 18 bytes

```
li_5*{_,2>f%0&},<`
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=li_5*%7B_%2C2%3Ef%250%26%7D%2C%3C%60&input=13)

Does not use any built in prime or factorization operators. Fairly brute force check for numbers being composite.

One observation that is used here is that we can easily calculate a safe upper bound for the numbers we have to test. Since every second number larger than 4 is composite, `4 + n * 2` is an upper bound for the n-th composite number.

Based on a suggestion by @Dennis, the latest implementation actually uses `n * 5` as the upper limit, which is much less efficient, but 2 bytes shorter.

Explanation:

```
li    Get and convert input.
_     Copy, will need the value to trim the list at the end.
5*    Calculate upper bound.
{     Start of filter.
  _     Copy value.
  ,     Create list [0 .. value-1].
  2>    Slice off the first two, leaving candidate factors [2 .. value-1].
  f%    Apply modulo with all candidate factors to value.
  0&    Check if one of the modulo results is 0.
},    End of filter.
<     Trim output to n values.
`     Convert list to string.
```

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript ES6, 88 chars

```
n=>{r=[];for(q=2;r.length!=n;++q)if(/^(..+)\1+$/.test("-".repeat(q)))r.push(q);return r}
```

Comment: I believe removing the variable assignment `f=` is legal.

Comment: @DankMemes, seems yes. http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/6915/32091

Comment: This is 83: `n=>eval('for(r=[],q=2;r.length-n;/^(..+)\\1+$/.test("-".repeat(++q))&&r.push(q))r')`

Comment: @DankMemes, cool :)

Comment: @DankMemes, seems like `eval` doesn't work in this way inside of lambda.

Comment: [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y1bxdz33/) works in the latest FF dev edition

Comment: @Qwertiy You can replace `r.length!=n` with `n&!r[n-1]`. It saves 2 characters.

Comment: @toothbrush, your version is correct only if `n` is odd.

Comment: @Qwertiy Sorry, I meant `n&&!r[n-1]` :'| It is the same length as `r.length<n` – one character shorter than `r.length!=n` – but this is supposed to be Code Golf, right? :-]

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, <s>49</s> 46 bytes

```
(`take`[x|x<-[4..],or[mod x y<1|y<-[2..x-1]]])
```

Usage example:

```
*Main> (`take`[x|x<-[4..],or[mod x y<1|y<-[2..x-1]]]) 13
[4,6,8,9,10,12,14,15,16,18,20,21,22]
```

How it works

```
  [x|x<-[4..]    ]           -- keep all x from the integers starting with 4 where
      ,or                    -- where at least one element of the following list is "True"
    [mod x y<1|y<-[2..x-1]]  -- "x mod y < 1" for all y from [2,3,...x-1]
(`take`[   ])                -- take the first n elements from the xes
                             -- where n is the parameter supplied when calling the function
```

Answer (score 2):

### F#, 78 bytes

```
fun n->(Array.filter(fun i->Seq.exists((%)i>>(=)0)[2..i-1])[|2..n*n|]).[..n-1]
```

Explained:

```
fun n->                                                                      
                                                           [|2..n*n|]          // Generate an array of integers from 2 to n * n
        Array.filter(fun i->                              )                    // Filter it using the following function on each element
                                                  [2..i-1]                        // Generate a list of possible divisors (from 2 to i-1)
                            Seq.exists(          )                                // Check if at least one of the divisors is valid, that is
                                       (%)i>>(=)0                                    // That i % it is equal to 0. This is equivalent to (fun d -> i % d = 0)
       (                                                             ).[..n-1] // Take the n first elements of the resulting, filtered array
```

Comment: This is a great answer, however it is a bit confusing that you use the variable `i` twice. I'm not too familiar with F#, but couldn't you perhaps use `j`?

Comment: Right, that does make it clearer. It did work due to shadowing, but I guess I forgot about readability while golfing the thing. ^_^'

Comment: I don't *ever* make that sort of mistake. Probably why I'm not good at golfing d:-D

Answer (score 1):

### C++ 109

```
int main(){int n,i,x=4;cin>>n;while(n){for(i=2;i<x-1;i++){if(x%i==0){cout<<x<<' ';n--;break;}}x++;}return 0;}
```

**Ungolfed**

```
int main(){
int n,i,x=4;cin>>n;
while(n)
{
for(i=2;i<x-1;i++)
{
if(x%i==0){cout<<x<<' ';n--;break;}
}
x++;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. Why not make a nice formatting for ungolfed version? 2. Seems like you have extra braces in both codes. 3. You can replace `while` by `for`.

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 103 bytes

```julia
n->(n>0&&println(4);n>1&&(i=0;c=big(6);while i<n-1 mod(factorial(c-1),c)<1&&(i+=1;println(c));c+=1end))
```

This uses Wilson's Theorem.

Ungolfed:

```julia
function f(n::Int)
    # Always start with 4
    n > 0 && println(4)

    # Loop until we encounter n composites
    if n > 1
        i = 0
        c = big(6)
        while i < n-1
            if mod(factorial(c-1), c) == 0
                i += 1
                println(c)
            end
            c += 1
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

## ECMAScript 6 – <s>107</s> <s>91</s> 84 bytes

```js
n=>eval('for(a=[],x=4;n&&!a[~-n];x++)for(y=2;y*2<=x;)if(x%y++<1){a.push(x);break}a')
```

The function returns an array of the first `n` composite numbers.

> `~-n` is a fancy way of writing `n-1`; same length, but much more fun, right?
>  The only reason I use `eval` is that the template `n=>eval('...returnValue')` is 1 character shorter than `n=>{...return returnValue}`.

### Old versions

```js
n=>eval('for(a=[],x=4;n&&!a[~-n];x++){for(z=0,y=2;y*2<=x;)if(x%y++<1)z=1;if(z)a.push(x)}a')
```

---

```js
n=>eval('for(a=[],i=4;a.length<n;i++)if((x=>{for(y=2,z=1;y*2<=x;)if(x%y++<1)z=0;return!z})(i))a.push(i);a')
```

### Output

```js
 0 -> []
 1 -> [4]
 2 -> [4, 6]
 3 -> [4, 6, 8]
13 -> [4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21, 22]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 44 bytes

Heavily inspired by [Nimi's earlier answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/57312/55329), replacing the predicate with a 2-byte shorter one based on `any` with a pointfree lambda instead of a nested list comprehension.

```hs
(`take`[x|x<-[4..],any((<)1.gcd x)[2..x-1]])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYyxCoMwFEV3v@INDgk0AdtOYocOHTp3tIIPjTFoYkhCidBvb9qKZ7lwuJwR/STmOSltFxfgsfogNL@Zl3KL0cIEIkW4Oulplg2XZyJtwEm0dXzHitVnzpsDmpWQihZcdj1EWh85j6xoGpo0KnOBfslgA38ZqBjsxd1ap0zIByBOYA85jP/ZrmUJdxNoSsXp0w0zSp9YZ@0X)
([thanks to Laikoni](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/57264/composite-number-sequences/144573?noredirect=1#comment354385_144573) for the accurate TIO link)

**Explanation:**

```hs
[x|x<-[4..],       -- consider all integers x >=4
[2..x-1]           -- consider all integers smaller than x
any((<)1.gcd x)    -- if for any of them 
    (<)1           -- 1 is smaller than
        .gcd x     -- the gcd of x and the lambda input
                   -- then we found a non-trivial factor and thus the number is composite
(`take`[  ])       -- take the first <argument> entries
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <sup><s>14</s></sup> 12 bytes

```
↑fṠöV¬thM%ḣN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR8A4P9odXNr///ihpFm4bmgw7ZWwqx0aE0l4bijTv///zIw)

-2 bytes from Jo King.

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
↑fȯ≠2LḊN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HbxLQT6x91LjDyebijy@////@mAA)

Uses the `Ḋ`ivisors function, if that is okay.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
Èâ Ê¨3}jU
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=yOIgyqgzfWpV&input=MTM)

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 7 bytes

```
∞'KḢḢ;Ẏ
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%88%9E%27K%E1%B8%A2%E1%B8%A2%3B%E1%BA%8E&inputs=5&header=&footer=)

```
∞       # The set of all positive integers
 '   ;  # Filtered by...
  K     # The list of factors of n
   ḢḢ   # Has length > 2
      Ẏ # Get first n
```

Using a isprime builtin doesn't actually save any bytes as 1 and 0 are considered nonprime.